# docopt does not parse args, just prints usage

Tags: python, docopt

I cannot get docopt to work. I have this simple example, which as far as I can tell is correct:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""usage: do.py name

"""
from docopt import docopt


args = docopt(__doc__)
print(f"Hello, {args['name']}!")
```

and it only ever prints:

```sh
$ ./do.py susan
usage: do.py name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [`docopt` documentation](https://github.com/docopt/docopt/blob/master/README.rst):

> - **<arguments>, ARGUMENTS**. Arguments are specified as either upper-case words, e.g. `my_program.py CONTENT-PATH` or words surrounded by angular brackets: `my_program.py <content-path>`.

Since `name` is neither upper case nor surrounded by angle brackets, it's not an argument. And since it is not an argument, it must fall into the category of

> - **commands** are words that do not follow the described above conventions of `--options` or `<arguments>` or `ARGUMENTS`, plus two special commands: dash "-" and double dash "--"…

And indeed, that is what it is:

```
$ ./do.py name
Hello, True!
```

It shows `True` because that's the value stored for commands, which serves to demonstrate that the command was entered. So that's probably not what you wanted. You could start with this model:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""usage: do.py hello <name>

"""
from docopt import docopt

args = docopt(__doc__)
if args['hello']:
    print(f"Hello, {args['<name>']}!")
```

which has more intuitive results:

```
 ./do.py hello susan
Hello, susan!
```

But it's possible that you don't really need commands at all:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
"""usage: do.py <name>

"""
from docopt import docopt

args = docopt(__doc__)
print(f"Hello, {args['<name>']}!")
```

```
$ ./do.py susan
Hello, susan!
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly it. I must say the documentation is not clear about this at all, even though the different patterns are indeed laid out there, their usage is not.